# Blazor: How to map two Entity to one DTO using autoMapper?

Tags: c#, .net, blazor, automapper, dto

Profile Entity:

```
public class Profile
    {
        public int PId { get; set; }
        public int PCode { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("Person")]
        public int PersonId { get; set; }
        public DateTimeOffset? TashkilDate { get; set; }
        public int? Category { get; set; }
        public bool IsEstelam { get; set; }
        public bool IsTaeed { get; set; }
        //navigation
        //MtoM
        public Person person { get; set; }
    }
```

Person Entity:

```
public class Person
    {
        public int PersonId { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string FatherName { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("Jens")]
        public int? JensId { get; set; }
        public string? NationalCode { get; set; }
        public string? ShSh { get; set; }
        public DateTimeOffset? BirthDate { get; set; }
        public string? OldFamily { get; set; }
        public int? PassportSerial { get; set; }

        //navigations
        //MtoM
        public ICollection<Profile> profiles { get; set; }

    }
```

ProfilePersonDTO:

```
public class ProfilePersonDTO
    {
        public int PId { get; set; }
        public int PCode { get; set; }
        public DateTimeOffset? TashkilDate { get; set; }
        public bool IsEstelam { get; set; }
        public bool IsTaeed { get; set; }
        
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string FatherName { get; set; }
        public string? NationalCode { get; set; }
        public string? ShSh { get; set; }

        public Person person { get; set; }
    }
```

My query in sevice:

```
var query = _dbContext.Profile.Where(u => u.PersonId == PersonIdParam);
var resultQuery = query
                       .Include(u => u.person)
                       .ProjectTo<ProfilePersonDTO>(_mapperConfiguration)
                       .AsAsyncEnumerable();
```

I write this for mapping:

```
CreateMap<Profile, ProfilePersonDTO>().ReverseMap();
```

but the Person field's not mapped to DTO field's. it means that "FirstName, LastName, FatherName, NationalCode and ShSh" are empty.

How shoule I Map this two entity to DTO using autoMapper?
(that fill out all field)

Comment: `Include` is not needed with `ProjectTo`. Also see https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Flattening.html#includemembers.

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu No no... it's misunderstanding!
i edit the query. please re check it. Include is used to join the Profile & Person in query.

Comment: See https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Queryable-Extensions.html#preventing-lazy-loading-select-n-1-problems. And surely a simple test will prove that point :)

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu I saw it but couldn't find my answer!
 please describe more

Answer (score -1):

I ask it another place & a person answer me!
I should add "ForMap" to "CreateMap" like this:

```
CreateMap<Profile, ProfilePersonDTO>()
  .ForMember(dst => dst.FirstName, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.person.FirstName))
  .ForMember(dst => dst.LastName, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.person.LastName))
  .ForMember(dst => dst.FatherName, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.person.FatherName));
```